# How to arrange this layout using Grid material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want a layout like this using Material-UI 
[image]

I tried the following:-

```
<Grid
        container
        spacing={2}
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-start"
      >
        <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography>Heading </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper style={{ height: 400 }}>Component A</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper style={{ height: 440 }}>
              <Typography>Center Text </Typography>
              <Typography>Center Text 1 </Typography>
              <Typography>Center Text 2 </Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Grid> 
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Paper style={{ height: 400 }}>Component C</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

The above gives me something like this:-
[image]

I want the Component C to be aligned with component A and also, Center Texts should be aligned centrally.

Can someone please help?
Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cbwzy8?file=/demo.js:240-1105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid should be like this

```
<Grid
    container
    spacing={2}
    direction="row"
    justify="flex-start"
    alignItems="flex-end"
  >
    <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography align="center">Heading </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper style={{ height: 400 }}>Component A</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper style={{ height: 440 }} align="center">
          <Typography>Center Text </Typography>
          <Typography>Center Text 1 </Typography>
          <Typography>Center Text 2 </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper style={{ height: 400 }}>Component C</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

In the parent grid you should have the `alignItems="flex-end"` and then in the Paper component the `align="center"`

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ekk802?file=/demo.js:240-1130)> Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the Paper `props` on [this link](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/paper/), I hope this would be helpful. thanks

```
import React from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const gridStyles = {
  border: '2px solid black',
  height: 440,
  borderRadius: 0,
  textAlign: 'center'
}

const styles = {
  border: '2px solid black',
  height: 440,
  borderRadius: 0,
}

export default function GridContainer() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={2}
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-start"
      >
        <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography>Heading </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper elevation="0" variant="outlined" square={false} style={styles}>Component A</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={4} spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper elevation="0" variant="outlined" square={false} style={gridStyles}>
              <Typography>Center Text </Typography>
              <Typography>Center Text 1 </Typography>
              <Typography>Center Text 2 </Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Grid> 
        </Grid>
        <Grid  item xs={4}>
            <Paper elevation="0" variant="outlined" square={false} style={styles}>Component C</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```